# Set Desktop Wallpaper to generated Bitmap

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmap, wallpaper

In my program I generate a bitmap, and I would like to set the computer's desktop background to this bitmap; how do I do this?

Comment: Show your program code..

Comment: No that one uses an image from file.

Comment: Yes, a file is required.

Answer (score 0):

You might generate a bitmap, save it to a file in, for example, the user's AppData, and then use victorantunes's link to set the desktop to the newly created file.